# Perl HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content

Tags: perl, http-headers, cgi

How can I set my server's HTTP response to:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
```

In PHP I would write `header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content')` but what about in Perl CGI?

I'm using this code but the client reports an HTTP 500 error

```
if ( defined $ENV{HTTP_RANGE} ) {

    my $startrange = 500;
    my $endrange = 900;
    $length = $endrange-$startrange;

    print qq{HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\n};
    my $range = $startrange.'-'.$endrange.'/'.$filesize;
    print qq{Content-Range: bytes $range\n};
}

print qq{Accept-Ranges: bytes\n};
print qq{Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$filename"\n};
print qq{Content-length: $length\n\n};
```

I have checked the error log, which says this:

> ```
> malformed header from script 'download.cgi': Bad header: HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
> ```

Comment: You can't get an HTTP 500 error on the server. You have given way too little information. Show your code and describe the network

Comment: @Borodin i have just updated the question, check the code, .. for some reason i'm getting HTTP 500 error but if i remove that line `print qq{HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\n};` i get 200 OK, i need to get 206 Partial Content for resumable download

Comment: @Borodin nevermind i have just selected the best answer :)

Comment: @Borodin, You are incorrect! CGI responses differs from HTTP responses! But what do I know about HTTP or CGI? I have only written most Engines for Catalyst, HTTP::Body, HTTP::Tiny and maintains FCGI ;o)

Comment: @chansen: Yes, my senses departed me and I made a mistake. Your reminder that this is CGI and not bare HTTP restored them. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not send a [HTTP status line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) for [Partial Content response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1) in a CGI script. Your script should send a correct [CGI response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-6):

> 1*header-field NL [ response-body ]

This should work:

```
Status: 206 Partial Content\n
Content-Range: bytes 500-900/12000\n
Content-Type: ?\n
```

Your script must also send a Content-Type header:

> [If an entity body is returned, the script MUST supply a Content-Type
> field in the response.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-6.3.1)

Comment: That what i was looking for. Thank you ^^

Comment: @Borodin, [CGI](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-6) responses differs from HTTP responses! First and second hyperlink refers to the HTTP standard, third and forth hyperlinks refers to the CGI standard.